# How would some of the top deck archetypes handle discard decks?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

In the past, I asked [how to fight a discard deck](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/27818/how-are-you-supposed-to-fight-a-discard-deck), one that's designed to just empty your hand as fast as possible with cards like Hymn to Tourach and many others. I have also read [this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/7747/how-can-i-play-around-targeted-discard) on playing around targeted discard.

However, at this point my friend has rebuilt his deck to a very high degree of efficiency. I often lose one of my opening lands to Hymn, and any creatures I get out are killed by targeted kill spells or board wipe like Drown in Sorrow. I never have a chance to play higher cost creatures because my hand gets emptied by discard spells. Lately I've been playing white weenie / equipment with some very good cards like Mother of Runes, Swords to Plowshares, Aegis of the Gods, Jitte, Stoneforge Mystic, and more, but ultimately all my creatures get killed by board clear and my hand is emptied. He will sometimes clear the board 3-4 times before I get killed by a combination of Black Vise, Quest for the Nihil Stone, and Guiltfeeder.

Again, I know discard decks aren't exactly one of the main Legacy archetypes. But I'm looking at decks like Miracles, Jund, D&T, OmniTell, Merfolk, and others, and to be frank, probably because I'm inexperienced with tournaments, I can't see how they would respond to this strategy. (Okay, I see how D&T stops it fairly easily, but not the others.)

How would some of the major Legacy archetypes respond to a discard deck?

Comment: I feel like there are multiple issues with this question. It does look like a duplicate of your own questions, but if it's not, it's either too broad, or primarily opinion-based. Answers that invite extended discussion are generally not appropriate for Stack Exchange. We tend to prefer objectively answerable questions about a specific problem; the more specific and answerable, the better.

Comment: To broad. There are a vast number of legacy archetypes.

Comment: The top decks probably wouldn't, because discard decks aren't in their metagame. If a good discard deck entered the Legacy metagame, the other decks would *change* (perhaps only in their sideboards), not try to respond while staying the same. (And Madness is a mechanic that just got a shot in the arm…) I suggest the application of SCIENCE: your friend should start playing his deck in Legacy tournaments so you can find out directly. ;) If it *is* really good, it could change the metagame! Either way, those matchups will tell you how to fight it.